# Crystal Report Viewer Accuracy

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I have several Crystal Reports which I am displaying in the Viewer in an ASP.NET web page. These reports are pretty advanced with tables and charts on them. One thing we have noticed is that the lines tend to take on a mind of their own, often out by a few pixels in the preview, or running off the bottom of the page. This is not a problem when running the reports in the Crystal designer application, only the web preview. Has anyone else seen or resolved this in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though not the same as using the report in an ASP.NET web page, I've fought similar formatting issues when exporting to HTML, pdf and other outputs.

Much of the time I find that though the line appears to be in line with the others it is not so when this happens the first thing I generally do is change the zoom drop down on the design screen from 100% to 400% and verify that they are exactly in line.

Also on the "Format" menu you can use the "Align" and "Make Same Size" menu options to make sure that objects are the same size and in the same line vertically or horizontally.

I've seen it to where it looked fine on the screen, but something in the export causes the objects to show differently if they are not lined up correctly.

Just throwing it out there. Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 yes you have to zoom in for lines and boxes since they have no "make same size" or "align" options.